# Merge multiple arrays (objects) and compare to another array

Tags: php, arrays

**My Problem**

Trying to create similar arrays so I can compare them.

I am creating a distribution list for files, the adding of the distribution list work fine, I list user surname, user forename and user department, these are selected and posted, foreach user I retrieve the users.user_id and store this in a distribution table (under distro_lis)t like so.

```
distro_id (AI, PK) | distro_list | policy_id
---------------------------------------------
        1          | 1 23 21 34  |     13
        2          | 10 22 21 34 |     15
        3          | 1 27 26 40  |     34
```

Now I working on the editing of the distribution list, so for a row, lets say row 1, I fetch the distro_list and parse it to get each user ID (from distro_list) using.

> $policyID is received in the method argument

```
$db = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT distro_list FROM distro WHERE policy_id = :policy_id');
        $db->bindParam(':policy_id', $policyID);
        $db->execute();
        $row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$ids = explode(' ',$row);
foreach ($ids as $user) {
            $db = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT user_forename, user_surname, user_dept FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY user_surname ASC');
        $db->bindParam(':user_id', $user);
        $db->execute();
        $row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($row);
        }
```

the var_dump($row) returns an array of arrays (objects.. not sure of the terminology here) which looks like so (print_r).

```
Array
(
    [user_forename] => fname1
    [user_surname] => sname1
    [user_dept] => dept1
)
Array
(
    [user_forename] => fname2
    [user_surname] => sname2
    [user_dept] => dept2
)
Array
(
    [user_forename] => fname3
    [user_surname] => sname3
    [user_dept] => dept3
)
```

the array that I want to compare it to looks like so (print_r).

```
array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_forename] => fname1
            [user_surname] => sname1
            [user_dept] => dept1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_forename] => fname2
            [user_surname] => sname2
            [user_dept] => dept2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_forename] => fname3
            [user_surname] => sname3
            [user_dept] => dept3
        )
)
```

I understand why the first array looks like that, because im var_dump'ing' after each iteration.  How can I get the first array (array of arrays or objects) into a single array so I can compare it to the second array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$list_users = array()
foreach ($ids as $user) {
    //...
    $list_users[] = $row;
}

var_dump($list_users);
```